# Best way to expose API from a library

Tags: c++, oop, dll

I am designing a Win32 library to parse the contents of the file (Columns and Values) and store it internally in a datastructure (Map). Now i need to expose API's so that the consumer can call those API's to get the results.

The file may have different formats eg FM1, FM2 etc. The consumer may query like

```
FM1Provider.GetRecords("XYZ");
FM2Provider.GetRecords("XYZ");
```

What i am planning to do is to have a CParser class that does all the parsing and expose the class.

```
CParser
{
  bool LoadFile(string strFile);
  Map<string,string> GetFM1Records(string key);
  Map<string,string> GetFM1Records(string key);
};
```

or

```
   class CResultProvider
   {
     virtual Map<string,string> GetRecords(string key)=0;
   }

   class CFM1ResultProvider : public CResultProvider
   {
      Map<string,string> GetRecords(string key);
   }

   class CFM2ResultProvider : public CResultProvider
   {
      Map<string,string> GetRecords(string key);
   }

   CParser
   {
      bool LoadFile(string strFile);
      CResultProvider GetFM1ResultProvider();
      CResultProvider GetFM1ResultProvider();
   };
```

Please suggest me which one of these approaches are correct and scalable considering i am developing a library.

Answer (score 3):

Your component seems to be dealing with two problems: parsing and storing. It is a good design practise to separate these into different components so that they can be used independently.

I would suggest you provide the parser only with callbacks for parsed data. This way the user of it can choose the most suitable container for her application, or may choose to apply and discard read data without storing.

E.g.:

```
namespace my_lib {

struct ParserCb {
    virtual void on_column(std::string const& column) = 0;
    virtual void on_value(std::string const& value) = 0;

protected:
    ~ParserCb() {} // no ownership through this interface
};

void parse(char const* filename, ParserCb& cb);

} // my_lib
```

BTW, prefer using namespaces instead of [prefixing your classes with C](http://www.jelovic.com/articles/stupid_naming.htm).

Comment: +1: He could make the parser-functions templates that take an output-iterator (whose type is a template parameter) to which they write the data. This is of course problematic if he wants them to be virtual functions.

Comment: Callbacks are more flexible then output iterators because the parser may spit out more than one type of element.

Comment: @Maxim: Agreed, I will have a class CMylib which is exposed. Two other classes CParser which only parses and CDatastore which stores the parsed data. I will create the CDataStore as a member variable of CMyLib class and CParser class will be instantiated while doing parsing and will be deleted immediately after parsing. Now the problem is how should i expose the API's for qureying my Library for data? So now you can consider that in my previous example the CParser is replaced with CMyLib

Comment: A callback interface and a parsing function should be sufficient. Updated my answer.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: The problem for me is should i expose the whole class or should i expose only certain functions like LoadFile, Parse, GetFM1Records and create a global object of my class inside my library and use that to perform operation

Comment: @Jeeva: From your description it sounds like there is no need to expose anything else but the parser and the parser callback interface.

Comment: I am sorry if i confused you. My problem is my library should parse and store the data which is of different format. I need to expose few API's so that the consumer can consume the parsed data. If i expose the class then the class has the member variable which is the DataStore which also i need to expose. Is that a right approach or what other way is there to expose some functions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4223/discussion-between-jeeva-and-maxim-yegorushkin)

Comment: dude, i'm gonna charge you a lot per line of live chat )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the client would only have to call `GetRecords` once, and then work with the map, the first approach I prefer the first approach because it is simpler.

If the client has to reload the map in different places in his code, the second approach is preferable, because it enables the client to write his code against one interface (`CResultProvider`). Thus, he can easily switch the file format simply by selecting a different implementation (there should be exactly one place in his code where the implementation is chosen).